# Office 365 Group Calendar Missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, office-365-groups

I created a SharePoint site based on an existing Group that was created in Teams. The strange part is there doesn't seem to be a Group Calendar associated with the Group. I tried to add it to the SharePoint Home page, and there is a link to the Group Calendar, but it just opens my calendar.

I've looked in my list of other Group calendars in Outlook Online and it is not listed. I'm the owner of the group so I permission to see it. It's like it just doesn't have one associated with it.

Is there a way to create one after the fact?

Comment: Strange.. If there's a Team, there's a SharePoint site with an associated Group, inbox and calendar. Are you able to start a new Team from scratch, maybe it was deleted?

Comment: How did you create sharepoint site in teams based on existing groups? Per my knowledge, we could only add Teams to your existing Microsoft 365 Group site.Hope following article is helpful:https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams-ama/why-the-teams-calendar-not-visible-in-outlook/m-p/300155